# Checkbox com propriedade checked não me retorna nenhum valor

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Eu tenho um código onde a pessoa deve selecionar uma modalidade da academia, por exemplo, o plano de artes marciais, a pessoa deve selecionar qual luta ela deseja. Então fiz o seguinte código:

```html
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle col-4"
     data-toggle="buttons"
     id="modalidade"
>
   <div *ngFor="let modalidades of planoDados?.PlanoModalidades">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-success col teste">
          <input
              #checkbox
              type="checkbox"
              name="modalidades"
              (click)="addCheckbox(checkbox.value)"
              [value]="modalidades.PlanoModalidadeID"
              [checked]="modalidades.PlanoModalidadeObrigatoria === '1'"
              [disabled]="modalidades.PlanoModalidadeObrigatoria === '1'"
          />
         <span class="lead">
            {{ modalidades?.PlanoModalidadeDescricao }}
         </span>
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

A lógica é, exiba um checkbox para cada modalidade existente, o valor vai ser o ID da modalidade, porém se uma das modalidades for obrigatória, ela já fica marcada e desabilitada, criei um array que vai receber exatamente os valores de cada checkbox.

Fiz esse código TS:

```js
private myCheckBox: any[] = [];

addCheckbox(i) {
    let index = this.checkBox.indexOf(i)
    if (index === -1) {
      this.checkBox.push(i)

    } else {
      this.checkBox.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
```

Porém não recebo o valor do checkbox que está marcado e desabilitado, alguma maneira de consertar isso? Ou até uma maneira melhor de pegar os checkboxes marcados do que pelo valor deles. Como pegar a propriedade "checked" de um checkbox?

Comment: É só pegar as modalidades que já são obrigatórias em **planoDados.PlanoModalidades[]** e juntar com os que forem sendo marcados no Html.

Comment: Vale a pena criar um array para todas as modalidades marcadas e para a obrigatória, colocar ela no array no ngOnInit?

Comment: Cara eu faria isso, pegaria os obrigatórios colocaria em um array junto com os que forem sendo marcados.

Comment: O Problema é esse, como faço para pegar o valor do que já está marcado por ser obrigatório?

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o `value` e o `checked` do seu `input[type=checkbox]` altere o seguinte conteúdo de

```
 (click)="addCheckbox(checkbox.value)"
```

para:

```
(click)="addCheckbox($event.target)"
```

e altere o código do método `addCheckbox` para poder efetuar a leitura do `value` e `checked`:

```
addCheckbox(checkbox: HTMLInputElement) {
    /* ... */
    console.log(checkbox.value, checkbox.checked);
}
```